# How to connect to Oracle database from google cloud functions

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

How to connect from Google Cloud Function (Python) to an Oracle database?

I tried using `jdebeapi` and it gives me the below error

```
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jpype/_jvmfinder.py", line 97, in find_possible_homes
    for childname in sorted(os.listdir(parent)):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/jvm'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I tried, I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/reach-oracle-db-in-serverless-271293f79861), and I will talk about it to the Google Next SF in April (session srv 212).

TL;DR: It's not possible because you have to use instant client and you can't install it on function. Use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) or the [Java runtime for Cloud Functions](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScC98jGi7CfG0n3UYlj7Xad8XScvZC8-BBOg7Pk3uSZx_2cdQ/viewform) (currently in alpha).

Comment: Would be great to meet you at Next, Guillaume!

Comment: @DustinIngram Yes, it could be great!

Answer (score 0):

FileNotFoundError

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/jvm'
```

This error states that the runtime env does not have the jvm libraries which are required for JaydebeApi library for making connection to the database engine.

so you can manually put this libraries and then set the ENV Variable of 'JAVA_HOME' before making the connection.

**How?**

**WORKAROUND:**
since the runtime Env for python 3.7 is **Ubuntu 1804** (not sure, you can check it with subprocess cmd 'cat/etc/os-release')

**Step 1:** Collect the Libraries for jvm/java
-Launch the Ubuntu 1804 GCP VM instance and run the following command

```
sudo apt update
#install java on ubuntu
sudo apt install default-jre
#go to the installation directory
cd /usr/lib
#copy the jvm dir to <user_home>, for zipping it properly 
cp -r jvm /home/<user>
cd /home/<user>
#install zip
sudo apt install zip
#zip the jvm directory 
zip -r jvm.zip jvm
#upload the zipped jvm.zip to gcs_bucket (however you wish, gsutil/download it from ssh browser and then manually uploading to gcs bucket) 
gsutil cp jvm.zip gs://<bucket-name>
```

Step 2: upload the source database engine specific driver jar to the same gcs_bucket

Step 3: Make a Cloud Function with following snippet included

using the HTTP Trigger Cloud Function here (you can use any)

**main.py**

```
#Importing all the required Libaries
import os
import jaydebeapi
import zipfile
from google.cloud import storage 
from google.cloud.exceptions import NotFound



def make_dir(dir_name):
    """Function to make directory"""
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
            os.makedirs(dir_name)
            print('Made an directory named: {}'.format(dir_name))
    except OSError as e:
        print("Error: %s : %s" % (dir_name, e.strerror))



def unzip(path_to_zip_file,directory_to_extract_to):
    """function to unzip the .zip file"""
    try:
        if os.path.exists(path_to_zip_file):
            with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
                zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)
            print('{} is extracted to {} directory'.format(path_to_zip_file,directory_to_extract_to))
        else:
            logger.debug('The file: {} does not exist'.format(file_name) )
    except OSError as e:
        print("Error: %s : %s" % (dir_name, e.strerror))



def download_gcs_file(bucket_name, gcs_path, local_path,projectid):
    """Func to download the file from gcs_bucket"""
    storage_client = storage.Client(project=projectid)
    try:
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        try:
            file_blob = bucket.get_blob(gcs_path)
            file_blob.download_to_filename('{}'.format(local_path))

        except NotFound:
            print('File Not Found for downloading File:{}'.format(bucket_name,gcs_path))
            raise

    except NotFound:
        print('Bucket: {} Not Found for downloading File:{}'.format(bucket_name,gcs_path))
        raise


def hello_world(request):
    """main function"""
    #since the working directory of cloud function runtime is /usercode, which is only read_only_filesystem, so we will create /tmp directory for downloading the jvm.zip and driver jar
    tmp_dir='/tmp/db_java'
    make_dir(tmp_dir)


    jvm_local_path='{}/jvm.zip'.format(tmp_dir) #jvm.zip will be downloaded here from gcs bucket
    jdbc_driver_loc='{}/<your-driver-jar>.jar'.format(tmp_dir) #jar will be downloaded here from gcs
    jdbc_class_name='<jdbc-driver-main-class>' #your jdbc_driver_main class
    download_gcs_file('<bucket-name>', 'jvm.zip', jvm_local_path,'<gcp-project-id>')
    download_gcs_file('<bucket-name>', '<your-driver-jar>.jar', jdbc_driver_loc,'<gcp-project-id>')
    unzip(jvm_local_path,tmp_dir)
    jvm_path='{}/jvm'.format(tmp_dir) 
    os.environ['JAVA_HOME']=jvm_path #setting the JAVA_HOME path
    user = '<db-username>'
    password = '<db-password>'

    jdbc_connection_string='<your-jdbc-connection-string>'

    conn = jaydebeapi.connect(jdbc_class_name,
                              jdbc_connection_string,
                              [user, password],
                              jdbc_driver_loc)
    import pandas as pd
    query='<your-sql-query>'
    df=pd.read_sql(query, conn)
    print(df)
```

**requirements.txt**

```
jaydebeapi
pandas
google
google-cloud
google-cloud-storage==1.28.0
```

you may encounter the error of memory limit exceeded; increase the memory of cloud function to 1 GB maybe, if the error "No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/jvm'" still persists set the ENV VARIABLE of the CLOUD FUNCTION as JAVA_HOME= /tmp/db_java/jvm  from UI and try again after some time

JaydebeApi uses jdbc_connection string refer [JaydebeApi pypi](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/) or database engine specific docs

*Have tested the approach for other db-engine's but not oracle (if oracle need's some more os packages, then I'm not sure this approach will work or not, but worth a try)*

Comment: you can delete /tmp/jvm.zip after unzipping, it will cost you less memory/size of cloud function

Comment: also please take the cost (network,memory,etc) and latency into consideration